# How to apply binary search for searching points/pairs in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, binary, binary-search

I want to search if the pair exists in the vector of pairs using binary search.
Here is my code: This code is only looking for the first value in pair:

Could you modify this code that it will be looking for the exact pair?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

struct compare { 
    bool operator()(const pair<int, int>& value,  
                                const int& key) 
    { 
        return (value.first < key); 
    } 
    bool operator()(const int& key,  
                    const pair<int, int>& value) 
    { 
        return (key < value.first); 
    } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<pair<int, int> > vect; 
    vect.push_back(make_pair(1, 20)); 
    vect.push_back(make_pair(3, 42)); 
    vect.push_back(make_pair(4, 36)); 
    vect.push_back(make_pair(2, 80)); 
    vect.push_back(make_pair(7, 50)); 
    vect.push_back(make_pair(9, 20)); 
    vect.push_back(make_pair(3, 29)); 

    sort(vect.begin(), vect.end()); 

    // printing the sorted vector 
    cout << "KEY" << '\t' << "ELEMENT" << endl; 
    for (pair<int, int>& x : vect) 
        cout << x.first << '\t' << x.second << endl; 

    // searching for the key element 3 
    cout << "search for key 3 in vector" << endl; 
    if (binary_search(vect.begin(), vect.end(), 
                                  3, compare())) 
        cout << "Element found"; 
    else
        cout << "Element not found"; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look for an exact pair, you need to provide the pair to `binary_search`, like this

```
if (std::binary_search(vect.begin(), vect.end(), std::pair{3, 42}))
 // ... found
```

Note that you don't need the custom `compare` function here. The default comparator does the right thing. (In fact, you *should* use the same comparator as used to `sort` the elements in the first place, otherwise `binary_search` will be broken).

Note that pre c++17, you need to provide the template arguments to `pair`, like this,

```
if (std::binary_search(vect.begin(), vect.end(), std::pair<int,int>{3, 42}))
 // ... found
```

If you want to find the *position* of the found element, you can use `lower_bound` like so,

```
auto lb = std::lower_bound(vect.begin(), vect.end(), std::pair<int,int>{3, 42});  

if (lb != vect.end())    
  std::cout << "Element found at position " 
            << std::distance(vect.begin(), lb);
```

Also, please don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` or `using namespace std;`

Comment: What about using lower_bound to find pair {3,42}? How to implement this?

Comment: I've added usage of `lower_bound` to the answer.

Comment: I need to say only if the pair exists or not. I don't want to return the near pair. I need to return true or false if pair{3,42} exists or not. Could you help me?

Comment: That's *exactly* what `binary_search` does.

Comment: But it is too slow. Which different method can I use? Maybe put these pairs to the set?
If yes how can I implement this?

Comment: Too slow? You can't do better than this on sorted data. Possibly it's too slow, because you are sorting the pairs before searching. If you don't need to sort for some other reason, then just use `std::find`.

Comment: I do not need to sort this, I need to only find a pair. What is the fastest way and how to implement this?

Comment: [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) shows how, and has examples.

Comment: Is there a faster way to search?

Comment: On unsorted data? Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: On sorted faster than binary search or lower_bound?

Comment: No. Not on sorted data.